# HTML5 Data attribute with complex JSON object and javascript

Tags: javascript, json, html

I came across a strange requirement (set by myself)...

I'm creating an easy to integrate ajax content loader plugin with lots of options and callbacks. Since the loader is a class and the developer can have multiple instances on a single page, I wanted to get rid of  all the ugly code required for every single initialization and decided to use data attributes instead - **they look awesome and proficient!**

The question is: How to add functions and javascript in general inside a data attribute?

Example:

```
var url = "someurl/goes/here/";
var Template = new TemplateEngine('Name', {
    onCreate: function(template, parts) {
        // do something with template parts
        template.ID += 1; 
    },
    onRender: function(template, parts) {
        template.addClass('flash');
    }
});
var settings = {
    container: DOM_ELEMENT|STRING,
    template: Template,
    disableDefaultRender: true,
    // a bunch of hooks and callbacks like this:
    onBeforeRequest: function(loader, data) {
        new_data = data;
        // modify request data somehow
        loader.requestData = new_data;
    },
    onRender: function(loader, data) {
        loader.renderData(data, function(part) {
            // define specific rendering logic for different template parts
            // in required
        });
    },
    onAfterRequest: function(loader, data) {
    },
    onError: function(loader, data) {
    }
    // etc, etc
};
var THE_LOADER = new SuperFancyAjaxLoader(url, settings);
```

My original idea is to somehow put all of the above inside the said data attribute:

```
<div data-fancy-stuff="{all-or-most-of-the-above}">more stuff</div>
```

and make the script itself find all elements and initialize instances for each of them like so:

```
var elements = document.querySelector('[data-fancy-stuff]');
for(item in elements) {
    try {
        var data = elements[item].getAttribute('data-fancy-stuff');
        var THE_LOADER = new SuperFancyAjaxLoader(data.url, data.settings);
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log('Someone messed with prototypes');
    }
}
```

Is the idea of putting javascript functions inside an attribute idiotic? Or is there a way to actually put some js inside an attribute?

I understand that if there's so much javascript required, it's pointless to try and put it inside an attribute, but in real life cases (for this particular task), I will have 3-5 content loaders per page, most of them (or all) will use the same template and rendering logic, but they will all have to modify the request data differently by themselves.

p.s. Eval is Evil.

**edit: I'm open to design proposals which do not involve third party MVC frameworks.**

Comment: Honestly, I would look at refactoring what you're doing. I don't understand why you just don't reference methods in your `data` attributes and run `window[elements[item].getAttribute('data-fancy-stuff)]` instead, as long as you make each function a member of window or whatever object you'd like. That's how you'd run the string. But I would never, ever suggest injecting a bunch of JavaScript inside of HTML attributes.

Comment: I have used that approach a couple of years ago and it works, but with time it gets more and more unfriendly to maintain.

Comment: Then I think it would be time to take a look at your code and try to restructure it, with all due respect.

Comment: This is more of a design question than actual implementation. My code works well and is entirely separated. I'm looking for a solution that will help me provide custom setup instruction to my classes other than writing javascript for each initialization.

Comment: and putting gobs of javascript as strings in html will be easy to maintain? I have a fairly state of the art IDE, it would never help me write script in string form though. What about testing? Sounds like a nightmare

Comment: In theory it should be a lot easier to maintain... After all changing data-request-data="{a:0,b:1}" is easier than looking for that particular object in a bunch of javascripts... I will not be the one who maintains the code. Writing the test will be tougher, but I will only write them once.

Comment: Maybe a more concrete example would help us out. I don't think a lot of us understand why you are passing in "all of the above data" into the HTML. It seems like a nightmare. I don't think a lot of us understand where or why you are injecting all this JS. Is it static? Is it dynamic?

Comment: As @Фагим Садыков said, the solution I'm working on (rather a framework) is related to what other frameworks (Amber, Angular) do. It is not a particular case I'm worried about, but this came out to be the most JS heavy till now. I have over 30 different instances for that content loader, 20 or more of them require a different request hook that modifies them slightly - this results in over 150+ lines of initialization in total (all split into different controllers). The goal is to combine them into one and let the html rendering engine control them.

Answer (score 0):

May be I don't understand well, but You want provide some JavaScipt modules/classes/objects through HTML5 attribute???

I think it's bad design. It's seems to be mixin of distinct layers.

So technically U have just ONE ability - to call eval, even after your PS because eval is the only point where JavaScript can get other JavaScript from String - ONLY.

But if U want dynamically load some complex javascript as reaction to data in some elements it's very good idea to learn and apply most ultimate thing for such scenarios - well-old-knownn require.js http://requirejs.org/. And if you want hardly bind DOM with some data and behavior you must to learn some of MVC JavaScript solutions - AngularJS, Backbome, Amber and so on.

By design u have to split your application to presentation layer where DOM will live and business layer were JavaScript will live. To bind them to each other you use string/JSON descriptors in DOM attribute and load JavaScript dynamically using on-fly head rewriting or by XHR+eval, such design is asynchronous, quick and is main choise of all solid network-based applications from gmail to all-other-cool-staff. To help build application with such model - require.js is best and most known helper.

Comment: I'm already using require but it will not help me provide setup objects for my instances. You misunderstood my idea, I already have split the application into layers because I have no other choice at the moment. My goal is to make most of the logic controllable by HTML attributes.

I do not have the opportunity to use any MVC solution...

Comment: "Control from attributes" is main approach and feature of ANY JavaScript MVC , because this idea in DOM/JS world is EXACTLY what is MVC in HTML. So now u go against wind and try to recreate things  that already made and work (and all of them based on eval because there's now other solutions for string to javascript). I think it's better to look to AngularJS. For me it's most balanced - it has reach functionality and document, but is not so abstract and for hardheart as backbone and is much more simple and understandable and simply-to-start than Amber.

Comment: In Angular u define an elment with special attributes for example <product mydata="...." myotherstuff="..." /> and then describe to MVC engine how you want to work with it by "directive" - Angular dynamically binds this functionallity with keeping scope and source DOM definition. It's pure HTML+Javasctipt solution, no special languages/translators required to work with it.

Comment: The framework I'm working on is MVC, but I'm not allowed to use existing solutions :) I have worked with angular before and know what it is capable of doing and how it's done. What I don't know and I'm trying to figure out is exactly what (not just a couple of theoretic sentences, but actual examples and guidelines) the logic behind controlling complex js classes with plain attributes.

Comment: EVAL, man... EVAL... nothing more, if U want to get return value just do it like var x = eval("_ = ("+myJavascript+")");